# ¿Por qué no se cambia el fondo?

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

Veran, tengo este problema con CSS, en donde mis ediciones no causan ningun impacto en la pagina, si voy al CSS y coloco el fondo verde o algun fondo de mi pc, guardo el archivo, refresco la pagina..... Y la pagina permanece igual.

No entiendo por que pasa esto, ayer, estaba investigando como colocar de fondo una imagen almacenada en mi pc y no se cargaba, al final me fui al extremo y decidi borrar todo el codigo dentro del CSS (guardando un respaldo en otro lugar), guardo el archivo, actualizo... Y Nada, la pagina sigue funcionando  y puedo desplazarme entre ella con el codigo CSS activo, pese a que el lugar de donde lo toma, esta eliminado (el contenido).

=/ ? Al final, no se como hice, pero pude colocar el fondo, pero resulta que hoy, quiero editar los px de un 'width' y vuelve a suceder lo mismo, coloco mil, tres mil pixeles, ninguno, borro el codigo, y nada de eso importa por que no se ven los cambios pese a que guardo y refresco la pagina.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
Por favor, proporciona un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene pinta de ser problema del caché del navegador. Borra el caché del navegador que estés usando, cierra y abre el navegador de nuevo.
Prueba con otro navegador.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso ! Muchas gracias, capo !

Comment: Me alegro de haber ayudado! :D